A question about the conclusions of the closed graph theorem
I am reading Hormander's notes for my Functional Analysis class. Its version of the Closed Graph Theorem states that

Let $T$ be a closed linear map (closed here means that its graph is a closed subset of $F_1\times F_2$) between a subspace $D_T$ of a Frechet space $F_1$ to a Frechet space $F_2$. Then $D_T$ is either of the first category or $D_T = F_1$ and $T$ is continuous. $\operatorname{im}(T)$ is either of the first category or $\operatorname{im}(T) = F_2$.

I am trying to find examples for each case. Could anyone help find examples where
$1.$ $D_T$ is of the first category and $\operatorname{im}(T)$ is of the first category (i.e. find a subspace of a Frechet space and the subspace is of the first category)
and
$2.$ $D_T = F_1$ and $T$ is continuous and $\operatorname{im}(T)$ is of the first category?
Thank you!

Both are very easy.  Hint: a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is of first category in $\mathbb R^n$.

Your question should include at least a rough outline of what you have tried so far and any ideas you have for potential progress. Otherwise it is not clear whether you have made an attempt at looking for any examples.
